# Is KeePass good for saving passwords for IT managers?

Tags: password-management, password

I am considering switching from passwords.rtf to a new system that is actually secure. I am a great fan of Dropbox and I am a great fan of efficient and quick working. If a passwords system requires 2 minutes to request a password, then it's not worth it. I use the document like 10 times a day, it helps me lots.

Also, I am not planning to use it for Firefox, I already use Xmarks for synchronizing passwords in Firefox and it works fine. I don't want to clutter my database. I already have far too many passwords. Maybe I will create 3rd Keepass database, called Firefox, next to passwords and server passwords.

On the internet I see a lot of positive experiences about LastPass, but I don't see any reason to use it if:

- I have no strong desire to replace the passwords manager of the browser, which is LastPass's raison d'être.
- I need quick access to the passwords. Not looking to spend minutes to copy a single passwords.

I might even consider using both, Lastpass for Firefox and Keepass for other passwords

So I am looking forward to hearing personal experiences with storing passwords etc. for servers. I do SSH logins via private keys, but it still leaves a lot of passwords e.g. Windows server accounts, MySQL accounts, etc..

Comment: Right. I also added accepted questions for the oldest 10 questions. I don't understand how I asked 30 questions and marked 15 as accepted and it still gave 7%. But it's fine now. All questions have accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely better than a ***plaintext file***(!!!).  LastPass keeps your stuff on their servers.... you may not want that.  I would use KeePass if I didn't have any commercial options.

Comment: What commercials options do you use?

Comment: I've seen CyberArk Password Vault in use & it works really well.  Also helps enforce password compliance (changing every so often).

Answer (score 1):

I don't mind it as we can create a standard db that we can share within the department. That way it is pseudo-centrally controlled so if someone changes the password for one of our on-line support login, we all know it.

Comment: Be sure to change the master password when anyone leaves the group.

Comment: Oh, totally. We have documentation and procedures we follow.